# Python (3.5) - Open File, Regex part of name, Rename - Loop

Tags: python

I have a bunch of files:

`File Completed for 123456 1 - Platform Junk (AP    .msg`

`File Completed for 1234566 1 - More Junk here and Stuf.msg`

`File Completed for 654321 1 - ® Stuff and Junk.msg`

So each file contains a 6 or 7 digit number (not including that `1` after the number), also some files have stupid R (registered trademark) symbols.

My goal is to search the current directory for all `.msg` files, find the 6 or 7 digit number, and rename the file to `123456.msg` or 11234567.msg`.

I have the regex that *should* work properly to extract the number:

`(?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{7})(?!\d)`

Now I just need to loop through all .msg files and rename them. I've got my foot in the door with the following code, but I don't quite know how to extract what I want and rename:

```
for filename in glob.glob(script_dir + '*.msg'):
    new_name = re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{7})(?!\d)')
```

Any help or step in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the regex is right here, don't take it the wrong way. I'll explain how to fix your code to rename your files step by step:

First, the `glob` pattern should be written using `os.path.join` or you'd have to end `script_dir` with `/`:

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(script_dir,'*.msg')):
```

Let's test your regex, adapted to keep only the regex match and drop the rest:

```
>>> re.sub(r".*((?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{7})(?!\d)).*",r"\1.msg","File Completed for 1234566 1 - More Junk here and Stuf.msg")
'1234566.msg'
```

Ok, now since it works, then compute the new name like this:

```
base_filename = os.path.basename(filename)
new_name = re.sub(r".*((?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{7})(?!\d)).*",r"\1.msg",base_filename) # keep only matched pattern, restore .msg suffix in the end
```

so the regex only applies to filename, not full path

And last, use `os.rename` to rename the files (check if something was replaced or rename will fail because source==dest:

```
if base_filename != new_name:
   os.rename(filename,os.path.join(script_dir,new_name))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! The only thing it's saying is on the `new_name` line "TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' ". Also, I believe there's an extra `)` at the end, so I removed it.

Comment: you're right! fixed. I assume you want to remove the matched pattern. was missing a parameter (the empty string), and the parameter order was wrong too:

Comment: So the code is now working great, except that it did the opposite: it removed the 6 or 7 numbers and left the text. But the numbers should stay and the rest disappear. Think that can be fixed with `^` in the regex?

Comment: I think we're almost there, I'm getting a `TypeError: sub() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'repl' and 'string'`. So I guess the method has parameters we need to fill? Can I just put a couple commas in? Also, I think there might need another `)` after `."` at the end maybe.

Comment: I feel like the easiest way might be to somehow invert the regex. I'm playing with it now trying to invert it, then we can use what you had before maybe.

Comment: Could I ask for your help one last time, if you'd review my comments above?

Comment: Sorry, there was 2 nested `re.sub`, edited out! inverting a regex is not what you mean. You mean "delete everything but ...", which is exactly what my fixed script does.

Comment: I actually removed the nested `re.sub` and it worked, so it's now complete! Thank you so much for your help, you're awesome! (Note: working line: `new_name = re.sub(r".*((?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{7})(?!\d)).*" ,r"\1.msg", base_filename)` )

Comment: our comments arrived at the same time. Too many edits in that post. My fault. Glad you found out & that works for you, thx for your patience and for accepting the answer (my post is edited for correctness).